# Missing "Show content" in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

My browsers are not displaying the http://superuser.com website as they should.

When I go here in IE, it renders incorrectly (my guess is it renders without CSS); then IE displays a message

> Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors

I click on "Show content" and everything looks OK. Web is colored and rendered as expected.
In Firefox I have the same issue but can't find any option/settings to correct it. I check many other web sites but everything looks OK.

I already:

Reset Firefox preferences "https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems"

And Add Exception "http://www.andrewlucking.com/archives/2007/10/secure-connection-failed/" for "https://superuser.com/"

I have: Win7 sp1 64-bit, Firefox 22.0, IE 9

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error message when browsing with Firefox? Does it occur only with SuperUser or with any of stackexchange sites?

Comment: No error message.It is only this web, http://stackexchange.com/ is OK; http://askubuntu.com/ NOT OK;

Comment: So, you mean both SuperUser.com and askubunut.com are BOTH incorrectly rendered?

Comment: Yes both. Even http://stackexchange.com/sites# have problem to show images in sites "boxes".

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by browser security settings, anti virus or firewall. It may also be caused by an incorrect time/ date on your computer.

However, since your issue is quite localised (ie, only affecting a few sites) I would think it's a problem with FireFox only.

I would open FireFox, click on Tools -> Options and ensure the privacy and security settings are ok.

I also suggest opening Firefox in safe mode in case it's a plugin issue. At the top of Firefox click the orange Firefox button ->  Help menu and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled.

Comment: privacy and security settings are OK = default

Comment: After "Reset Firefox preferences", Add-ons was gone

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED by myself - accidentally***

How I found solution ? I just try Opera. Opera behaved same as Firefox. But my curiosity told me to show picture on page http://stackexchange.com/sites which was not showed. I make right click and choose "Open image in new tab" I've got message "Invalid certificate" and choose "Continue Anyway".

Process in pictures: http://slim.szm.sk/Opera/

I did similar in Firefox, and now, everything is OK !

But question is:
Why I need show only one element from page, to get security message? Where is something like in IE: "Show content" ?!

Comment: You will need to ask a new question - you can't ask questions within answers. This isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, so Question at the top, only answers underneath! :) Feel free to ask a new question or edit your original question... By the way, your rep is now 11 so you can include pictures in your posts (recommended)